# Не могу получить свойства getEnvironment, из файла properties в spring xml context

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-core

Содержание файла `people.properties`:

```
knight.age=34  
knight.name=Pedro
```

Содержание файла `annotationsBased.xml`:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:people.properties"/>
<bean class="ru.miron.SOWithDocs.Entities.Person" id="knightCreatedUsingPropertiesFile">
    <constructor-arg name="age" value="${knight.age}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="${knight.name}"/>
</bean>
```

При получении:

```java
ApplicationContext XMLcontext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("annotationsBased.xml");
System.out.println("Knight created using properties file - " + XMLcontext.getBean("knightCreatedUsingPropertiesFile"));
```

Вывод следующий:

```
Knight created using properties file - Person [age=34, name=Pedro]
```

Это означает, что свойства с файла успешно загрузились в пространство имен `SpEL`.

---

Почему при выполнении следующего кода далее:

```java
System.out.println(XMLcontext.getEnvironment().getProperty("knight.age"));
```

Вывод - `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существуют следующие два метода интерфейса `Environment` для получения таких свойств с помощью `SpEL`:

> .resolveRequiredPlaceholders(text);
>   .resolvePlaceholders(text);

Отличаются они незначительно.

`.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(text)`:

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if given text is null or if any placeholders are unresolvable

`resolvePlaceholders(text)`:

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if given text is null

При выполнении следующих строк кода:

```
System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders("${knight.age}"));
System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders("${knight.name}"));
```

Получаем вывод:

> 34
>   Pedro

Это самый простой пусть. Также это можно провернуть, использовав аннотацию [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:people.properties") // can include many .properties files
public class EnvironmentFabric {
    @Autowired
    public Environment en;

    @Value("${knight.name}")
    public String knightName;
    @Value("${knight.age}")
    public int knightAge;

    public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return en;
    }

    public void printKnight() {
        System.out.println("knight name: " + knightName + ", knight age: " + knightAge);
    }
}
```

И при выполнении следующего кода:

```
EnvironmentFabric enF = context.getBean("environmentFabric", EnvironmentFabric.class);
System.out.println(enF.getEnvironment().getProperty("knight.name"));
System.out.println(enF.getEnvironment().getProperty("knight.age"));
enF.printKnight();
```

Вывод будет следующим:

> Pedro
>   34
>   knight name: Pedro, knight age: 34

Ответ построен [на этой статье](https://www.netjstech.com/2016/11/how-to-read-properties-file-in-spring-framework.html#PropertySourceEnvironment).
[Статья с более подробным разбором темы](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).

Answer (score 0):

Файл `properties` подключается к контексту `spring` в классе конфигурации и записывается в бин `Environment`. См. [Properties with Spring and Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring). Далее этот бин можно инжектить в любой другой бин.

Например там же, в классе конфигурации:

```java
@Bean(name = "knight1")
public Person knight(Environment environment) {
    Person knight1 = new Person();
    knight1.setAge(environment.getProperty("knight.age"));
    knight1.setName(environment.getProperty("knight.name"));
    return knight1;
}
```

Или в конструкторе класса контроллера:

```java
@Autowired
public Controller(Environment environment) {
    Person knight2 = new Person();
    knight2.setAge(environment.getProperty("knight.age"));
    knight2.setName(environment.getProperty("knight.name"));

    this.knight2 = knight2;
}
```

---

**Если файлов с пропертями много**, тогда при подключении каждого из них указываем ему имя:

```java
@PropertySource(name = "knight1.properties", value = "classpath:resources/knight1.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
@PropertySource(name = "knight2.properties", value = "classpath:resources/knight2.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

добавляем бин `propertySources`:

```java
@Bean
public PropertySources propertySources(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    return environment.getPropertySources();
}
```

и далее получаем пропертя из этого бина:

```java
@Bean(name = "knight1")
public Person knight(@Value("#{propertySources.get('knight1.properties')}")
                                 ResourcePropertySource propertySource) {
    Person knight1 = new Person();
    knight1.setAge(propertySource.getProperty("knight.age"));
    knight1.setName(propertySource.getProperty("knight.name"));
    return knight1;
}
```

---

#### Пример: knights-project

Структура проекта:

```
knights-project
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── knights
│       │       ├── Controller.java
│       │       ├── Person.java
│       │       └── WebAppConfig.java
│       └── resources
│           ├── knight1.properties
│           └── knight2.properties
└── pom.xml
```

**Controller.java**

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {
    private final HashMap<String, Person> band;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(@Qualifier("knight1") Person knight1,
                      @Value("#{propertySources.get('knight2.properties')}")
                              ResourcePropertySource propertySource) {

        Person knight2 = new Person();
        knight2.setAge(propertySource.getProperty("knight.age"));
        knight2.setName(propertySource.getProperty("knight.name"));

        this.band = new HashMap<>();
        this.band.put("knight1", knight1);
        this.band.put("knight2", knight2);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index.html"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> mainPage() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(band);
    }
}
```

**Client side:** index.html

```
{
  "knight2": {
    "age": 35,
    "name": "González"
  },
  "knight1": {
    "age": 34,
    "name": "Pedro"
  }
}
```

**Person.java**

```java
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Object age) {
        this.age = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(age));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Object name) {
        this.name = String.valueOf(name);
    }
}
```

**WebAppConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource(name = "knight1.properties", value = "classpath:resources/knight1.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
@PropertySource(name = "knight2.properties", value = "classpath:resources/knight2.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        servletContext
                .addFilter("encoding-filter", encodingFilter)
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySources propertySources(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        return environment.getPropertySources();
    }

    @Bean(name = "knight1")
    public Person knight(@Value("#{propertySources.get('knight1.properties')}")
                                     ResourcePropertySource propertySource) {
        Person knight1 = new Person();
        knight1.setAge(propertySource.getProperty("knight.age"));
        knight1.setName(propertySource.getProperty("knight.name"));
        return knight1;
    }
}
```

**knight1.properties**

```
knight.age=34
knight.name=Pedro
```

**knight2.properties**

```
knight.age=35
knight.name=González
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>knights-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>knights-project</artifactId>
    <name>knights-project</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```